# Setting axis range shifts image

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Setting axis range in matplotlib for some reason draw image shifted, how to fix this?

```
sz = 16
img = np.zeros((sz,sz), np.uint8)
img[:2,:] = 255
img[-2:,:] = 255
img[:,:2] = 255
img[:,-2:] = 255
img[sz//2-1:sz//2+1,sz//2-1:sz//2+1] = 255
print('img.shape', img.shape)

# v1
# axes = plt.gca()
# axes.set_xlim([0,sz])
# axes.set_ylim([0,sz])
# v2
plt.axis([0, sz, 0, sz])
plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update:**

With sz-1 axes are not aligned with end of image and not contain 16:
[image]

**Update:**

based on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest answer, ticks are centered to pixel center, but I need them centered to pixel corners.

```
sz = 8
img = np.zeros((sz,sz), np.uint8)
img[:1,:] = 255
img[-1:,:] = 255
img[:,:1] = 255
img[:,-1:] = 255
img[sz//2-1:sz//2+1,sz//2-1:sz//2+1] = 255
print('img.shape', img.shape)

plt.axis([-0.5, img.shape[1]-0.5, img.shape[0]-0.5, -0.5])
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update:**

based on @haijohn answer, horizontal ticks are not at the each pixel.

```
sz = 8
img = np.zeros((sz,sz), np.uint8)
img[:1,:] = 255
img[-1:,:] = 255
img[:,:1] = 255
img[:,-1:] = 255
img[sz//2-1:sz//2+1,sz//2-1:sz//2+1] = 255
print('img.shape', img.shape)

plt.axis([0, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 0])
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0, sz, 0, sz], interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: setting `sz` to `sz-1` in `plt.axis([0, sz, 0, sz])` seemed to fix it

Comment: @Axois With sz-1 it still draw axes not right, see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sz = 8
img = np.zeros((sz,sz), np.uint8)
img[:1,:] = 255
img[-1:,:] = 255
img[:,:1] = 255
img[:,-1:] = 255
img[sz//2-1:sz//2+1,sz//2-1:sz//2+1] = 255
print('img.shape', img.shape)

plt.axis([0, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 0])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(ticks=range(sz+1))
ax.set_yticks(ticks=range(sz+1))
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0, sz, 0, sz], interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

maybe this

```
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0, sz, 0, sz], interpolation='nearest')
```

reference to  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html

Answer (score 2):

Pixels are centered at integer positions by default. E.g. the first pixel ranges from -0.5 to 0.5, thus being centered at 0.

To set the same axis limits as chosen by default, subtract 0.5 from the shapes,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(5,5)

plt.axis([-0.5, a.shape[1]-0.5, a.shape[0]-0.5, -0.5])
plt.imshow(a)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The updated plot looks as expected to me. What's the problem?

Comment: Actually I was looking for this kind of axis
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57792885/1179925
but your answer is helpfull anyway.